# What's the policy on YouTube screen recording?

Tags: discussion

I'm a fairly new Stack Overflow contributor, and I want to know the policy/consensus on sharing YouTube screen recording as a supplemental resource.

I came across an AWS question that was answered, and it appeared the question asker wanted a more straightforward answer. He hadn't had too much experience with the topic and was about to go live with an application. I sensed that he wanted a walk through screen recording video. I will admit the video is fairly long, but I believe it caters to what he needed.

How does everyone feel about YouTube tutorials as a supplemental resource?

And do you think the video was too long in this scenario?

Link to the question: *[Already have EC2 Instance Running Wordpress, How to Create/Configure Auto Scaling & Elastic Load Balancer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48046628/already-have-ec2-instance-running-wordpress-how-to-create-configure-auto-scalin)*

Comment: If the video was gone tomorrow, would the answer (as it is posted here) still be useful? If *yes* then I wouldn't consider it a problem, if *no* then it shouldn't be posted as an answer. If someone comes across it in one year and just finds a dead youtube link then it's not very useful to them.

Comment: I've always preferred text (with screenshots) over video. The advantage is that text can be skimmed. So I can quickly find the parts that are relevant to my situation.

Comment: @S.L.Barth saeeem. Speeding up a video to 2 or maybe 3x doesn't come even close to skimming a text.

Comment: An alternative, particularly for shorter videos that don't need sound would be to use an animated gif. These can be hosted where normal SO images go so won't vanish.

Comment: Related: [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really "good answers"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231)

Comment: A video showing someone labouriously typing in a large C source just to point out a typo would be *so* annoying.

Comment: The question is about server management, not software development.

Comment: Even better: post it directly in the answer as an animated GIF. Or not.

Comment: Aside: any video platform other than YouTube would be better. The censorship there - at the behest of both copyright holders and SJWs - is complex, sweeping, and unpredictable, and it's hard to keep track of what's happening because it doesn't trigger notifications for content creators and is often done on a per-country level. You've got basically no guarantee that anything you post will still be watchable by most of your readers 6 months from now. I would stay away; you're just baking a bomb with a random timer into part of your answer, otherwise.

Comment: We are not here to provide tutorials. I mean, I guess you can provide tutorials if you want to but I wouldn't, it's not worth your time.

Comment: @MarkAmery Are you saying it's impossible to make a tutorial that doesn't contain copyright content or content that will "offend" SJWs?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton any video tutorial involving using third-party software with a UI (whether for desktop or the web) necessarily contains copyrighted content (the graphical design of the UI), so yeah, I'm pretty much saying that. It'd likely be "Fair Use" under US law, of course, but YouTube doesn't necessarily care. And then there's other bits of content like stock sound effects from software that could also bite you. I don't know whether there's a history of those sort of violations being enforced, but I know lots of crazy stuff is and the scope seems to be expanding.

Answer (score 54):

> How does everyone feel about YouTube tutorials as a supplemental resource?

IMO, it's just like any other external resource.  As long as it is truly a *supplemental* resource, it's fine to include the link to the video.  You must be sure the answer isn't a "link only answer" and that the answer can stand alone without the video.  These kinds of videos are fine for comments.

Comment: Thanks. It appears my biggest mistake was posted the link as an answer instead of a comment.

Comment: Also, make sure that you're not just posting links to your YouTube channel to boost views. This can be seen as excessive self-promotion and can lead to your answers being deleted.

Answer (score 9):

It's a good **addition** to an answer, but you should include written instructions in your answer as well. Imagine that your channel gets deleted or somebody can't watch the video (has handicapped vision/slow network connection etc.)

A good way of doing this would be something like a list of instructions, followed by the link of the video:

> 1. Open **Foo/Bar...**
> 2. Click on the **Baz** option in the **Foobar** section.
> 3. Toggle the switch found under **Foo**.
>
> [Here is a video that shows the process.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ)

Comment: I removed the link to an actual video, since this is just an example

Comment: @Machavity You might want to consider a *roll*back ;)

Comment: Heh. I thought the URL looked familiar.

Comment: I get ***"The uploader has not made this video available in your country."*** This might also be something to consider when posting YT videos.

Comment: Note that if the tutorial is only a short amount of steps, an embedded .gif would have my preference. That way, it's immediately visible to all users. The use case for video's is really limited.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Yes, I agree. This answer is true for longer processes.

Answer (score 6):

If you've never read it before, I would highly suggest taking a moment to read this Meta.SE

[Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer)

Now, lots of YouTube videos are helpful, but understand that

1. A link cannot stand by itself. YouTube is particularly volatile, since you never know if the account that posted the video actually owns the copyright to said video (if I had $1 for every YouTube link removed by DMCA...)
2. People make instructional videos all the time and then come here to link them so they build their viewership, earn money on ads, etc.